# Suspending a container in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to suspend the main process in a docker container running in a kubernetes pod.  I have attempted to do this by running

```
kubectl exec <pod-name> -c <container-name> kill -STOP 1
```

but the signal will not stop the container.  Investigating other approaches, it looks like `docker stop --signal=SIGSTOP` or `docker pause` might work.  However, as far as I know, kubectl exec always runs in the context of a container, and these commands would need to be run in the pod outside the context of the container.  Does kubectl's interface allow for anything like this?  Might I achieve this behavior through a call to the underlying kubernetes API?

Comment: `kubectl stop <pod name>` wont solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as far as I know `kubectl stop` and `kubectl delete` will take down a pod from the cluster but do not allow for keeping the pod in the cluster with a suspended main process.

Comment: I think you need to scale replication to 0

Comment: AFAIK you can not stop containers to stay around: Kubernetes schedules containers, it is not a overlay docker manager.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I would like to test what happens if a process goes into a 5-10 sec GC pause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So kubernetes does not support suspending pods because it's a VM kinda behavior, and since starting a new one is cheaper it just schedules a new pod in case of failure. In effect your pods should be stateless. And any application that needs to store state, should have a persistent volume mounted inside the pod.

The simple mechanics(and general behavior) of Kubernetes is if the process inside the contaiener fails kuberentes will restart it by creating a new pod.

If you also comment what you are trying to achieve as an end goal I think I can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I figured I wanted to do something unsupported.  I am trying to make a stateful pod for testing.  Specifically I am testing what happens when nodes of an ipfs-cluster go offline for a period of time and then rejoin the network.  My jugaad solution is to start a dummy process as the main process of the container and then spawn the actual process as a child so that it can be stopped with a `kill -STOP` command using `kubectl exec`

Comment: if you want to make it stateful try to do volume mount using PersistentVolume and store all the data you want to be persistent there that way even if your process dies and hence pod dies k8s will restart the pod and since the data is else where and safe your application will again be in same state

Comment: I think a use-case for pausing a pod would be if you have a running process for which you want to preserve it's RAM state. For example, if you have a Jupyter Notebook pod that you want to migrate to another node without killing the Jupyter Kernel.

Comment: "The simple mechanics(and general behavior) of Kubernetes is if the process inside the contaiener fails kuberentes will restart it **by creating a new pod**."  The bold part is not correct. The failed container will be restarted in the same pod. There is no new pod being created in this case.

Answer (score 15):

You could set the replicaset to 0 which would set the number of working deployments to 0. This isn't quite a Pause but it does Stop the deployment until you set the number of deployments to >0.

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/<pod name> --namespace=<namespace>
```

Comment: what about there's two container for a pod? i need to stop 1 because it is depends to another one and it error effect restart the whole of a pod in infinity loop!

Comment: That command will halt all containers in the pod. Kubernetes has excellent state management though so it will probably crash until the container is fixed and then start working. But to be honest, and without knowing your use-case, i think you should split them apart into two pods in one namespace. You'd still be able to connect to the container within the same namespace without too much difficulty (use the service-name:port). If your porting something from docker compose then use a helm chart as a cheatsheet for comparable set-ups.